# Print "real length" of a ruler with the fgruler package

Tags: latex-misc

I created some rulers with the `fgruler` package and printed them, while setting the printer to print the real size of the page (scale 100). However, when I measured them with an electronic caliper, every ruler is smaller than their "true size". The relation is approximately 1 cm in the page --- 0.96 cm in reality.

Is it something that I am doing wrong with the package, or are there some printer shenanigans going on?

Thanks in advance!

The generated PDF looks like this:

[image]

The latex code that I used:

```
\pdfminorversion=0
\pdfcompresslevel=0

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[type=none]{fgruler}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

%\fgruler{upperleft}{1cm}{2cm}

Created with the fgruler \LaTeX package. 

The thickness of each line should be 0.1 mm or 100 um. 

\vspace{0.5cm}

\rulerparams{0.01cm}{}{}{}{}

\ruler{rightdown}{9cm}

\vspace{0.5cm}

\ruler{rightup}{9cm}

\vspace{0.5cm}

\ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} 

\vspace{0.5cm}

\rulerparams{0.01cm}{}{red}{}{}

\ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} 
\hspace{0.5cm} 

\vspace{0.5cm}

\rulerparams{0.01cm}{}{blue!75!black}{}{}

\ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} 


\vspace{0.5cm}

\rulerparams{0.01cm}{}{green!50!black}{}{}

\ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} \ruler{upright}{3cm} \hspace{0.5cm} 
\vspace{0.5cm}

The square should be 1 cm x 1 cm, with a line thickness of 0.25 cm.


\tikz{
    \fill(0,0) rectangle(1cm,1cm);
    \fill[white](.25cm,.25cm)rectangle(0.75cm,0.75cm);
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `fgruler` allows you to draw stuff at absolute positions (e.g. your commented out line). Can you measure the distance of the drawn objects to the page edge and report back whether they match, or whether they are longer than expected? // Additionally, you also drew a box using tikz; does that box have the right size when printed?

Comment: I will measure the page edge tomorrow, but for the box, the dimensions are not correct. The box's side should be 1 cm (as the rulers), but it is approx. 0.96 cm. Same with the line thickness, it is approx. 0.22 cm instead of the 0.25 cm that it should be.

Comment: Searching on Google a bit, it appears that this is a common complaint among the community that designs their own PCBs: laser jet print outs can be 4-5% smaller than specified in the PDF files. People usually work around it by finding an adequate zoom factor through trial and error.

Comment: I did it as you said, just gave scaling values until I got the correct one. Thanks a lot @WillieWong. If you'd like, you can post it as an answer; otherwise I will try to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably with your printer and not with the generated PDF file.

Searching on Google a bit, it appears that this is a common complaint among the community that designs their own PCBs: laser jet print outs can be 4-5% smaller than specified in the PDF files. People usually work around it by finding an adequate zoom factor through trial and error.

If you wish to double check the PDF file generated, you can load it into a graphics software like Inkscape to see if the file itself shows up correctly.